# Wordpress ajax form submit post url return 404

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to submit my custom form information, and catch the data from custom endpoint, but when submit the form through ajax, it always return post url not found, 404.

In my php class:

```
class PersonalForm {
private $plugin_Path;

private $plugin_Url;

private $error_info;

public function __construct( $plugin_Path,  $plugin_Url ) {
    $this->plugin_Path = $plugin_Path;
    $this->plugin_Url = $plugin_Url;
    $this->init();

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this,'load_style' ) );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this,'load_function' ) );

    add_shortcode( 'personal-container-1', array( $this,'load_shortcode' ) );
}

public function load_shortcode(){
    include_once( $this->plugin_Path . 'templates/personal-form.php' );
}

public function load_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'personal-form-style', $this->plugin_Url. "public/css/personal-form.css", array(), null );
    wp_register_style( 'selfie-style', $this->plugin_Url. "public/css/selfie-style.css", array(), null );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'personal-form-style' );
    wp_enqueue_style('selfie-style' );
}

public function load_function(){
    wp_register_script( 'personal-form-function', $this->plugin_Url . 'public/js/personal-form-function.js', array('jquery'), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'personal-form-function' );

    $this->wp_localize_script();
}

public function load_selfie_function(){
    wp_register_script( 'selfie-function', $this->plugin_Url . 'public/js/selfie-function.js', array('jquery'), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_script('selfie-function' );
}

/**
 * Pass data to JavaScript.
 * @return bool
 */
public function wp_localize_script(): bool {
    global $wp_scripts;

    if ( ! ( $wp_scripts instanceof WP_Scripts ) ) {
        _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, 'personal-form-info' );
        return false;
    }

    return $wp_scripts->localize( 'personal-form-function', 'data_obj',
        array(
            'post_url' => get_rest_url( null, 'tantech-form-post/v1/personal-post'),
            'post_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
        ) );
}

/**
 * Initialize Rest API routes
 * @return void
 */
public function init(): void {
    /**
     * Register a route for REST API
     */
    add_action( 'reset_api_init', array( $this, 'register_routes') );
}

/**
 * Register a route for REST API
 * @return void
 */
public function register_routes(): void {
    register_rest_route( 'tantech-form-post/v1', '/personal-post', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'handle_content_form' ),
        )
    ) );
}

/**
 * submit call back info
 * @param $data
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle_content_form( $data ){
    echo 'Endpost owrking';
}
```

}

In javascript file:

```
(function($){
jQuery('#person-register-form').submit(function( event  ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // alert(data_obj.post_url);

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: data_obj.post_url,
        data: {
            action: 'personal_form_submit',
            form_data: data,
            headers: { 'X-WP=Nonce': data_obj.nonce},
            data: data
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert('Submit Success.');
        }
    })
})
```

})(jQuery)

Chrome console result:
[image]

[image]